# Mold growing on blow-off tube water -- batch ruined?

Tags: blow-off, mold

I'm brewing my first batch with a brooklyn brew show all-gain kit.  I skipped the airlock and left the blow-off tube in place in a pot of bleachy water.  It's been there for the past two weeks.

Today, I go look at it to start bottling and I see mold growing on the water that the blow-off tube was plugged into!  I guess the bleach evaporated..

Is the batch ruined?[image]

And to avoid this in the future, I suppose I should just re-up the bleach every so often?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not at all ruined. The airlock is working exactly as intended. Unless there is a growth of mold all the way up the blow-off tube and into the fermentor, you're fine.

It's not so much that the bleach evaporated as it was denatured by the copious blow-off material. You don't need to "re-up" on bleach (you really don't even need bleach) so much as discard that nasty-ass blow-off water after the ferment is far enough along that the blow-off tube is not really needed.